# Creating responsive Google DFP ads

Tags: double-click-advertising

I am following the last example on this link:https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/4578089?vid=1-635774352437004756-19071376

its resizing however my ad is not showing for some reason, pls see below:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>GPT Training - Responsive Test Page</title>
<script>
 // Load GPT asynchronously
 var googletag = googletag || {};
 googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
 (function() {
   var gads = document.createElement('script');
   gads.async = true;
   var useSSL = 'https:' == document.location.protocol;
   gads.src = (useSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
       '//www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js';
   var node = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   node.parentNode.insertBefore(gads, node);
 })();

</script>
<script>

 // GPT slots
 var gptAdSlots = [];
 googletag.cmd.push(function() {

   // Define a size mapping object. The first parameter to addSize is
   // a viewport size, while the second is a list of allowed ad sizes.
   var mapping = googletag.sizeMapping().

   // Small ad
   addSize([100, 100], [88, 31]). 

   // Accepts both common mobile banner formats
   addSize([320, 400], [[320, 50], [300, 50]]). 

   // Same width as mapping above, more available height
   addSize([320, 700], [300, 250]).

   // Landscape tablet 
   addSize([750, 200], [728, 90]). 

   // Desktop
   addSize([1050, 200], [1024, 120]).build();

   // Define the GPT slot
   gptAdSlots[0] = googletag.defineSlot('/1034652/Z103Home_TopLeaderboard', [728, 90], 'div-gpt-ad-1441833752374-0').
       defineSizeMapping(mapping).
       addService(googletag.pubads());
   googletag.pubads().setTargeting("test","responsive");

   // Start ad fetching
   googletag.enableServices();
 });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>GPT Training - Responsive Test Page</h1>

<div id="div-gpt-ad-1441833752374-0"> 
   <script>
     googletag.cmd.push(function() {
       googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1441833752374-0');
     });
   </script> 
</div>

<p><span>GPT responsive ads do not resize on change in the size of the browser.
  You can add your own custom code to refresh the ad slots on resize.
  To demonstrate responsive capabilities, re-size your window and refresh the page.</span></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This example code you have should initially display an ad when you open it on your browser. How can you say its resizing but there is no ad? This confuses me.

**What I actually don't see is a code that refreshes your ad slot on window resize.**